# JQuery positioning an element on the mouse click position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script which gets the X and Y coordinates of the clicked area of a container relative to its width and height (not the page's).

Here is a clicked x and y (return value by the function):

```
var x = 7;
var y = 13;
```

Now I want to use its return value to position an element at the same time the mouse is clicked.

Here is what I do right after getting the coordinates:

```
$(this).append("<div style='width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: red; " +
                "position: relative; left:"+ relX +"px; top: "+ relY +"px;'></div>");
```

The  gets created, and gets placed in the container. But the problem is that i gets placed exactly symmetrically. I have change the left ro right and vice versa but nothing changes, when I change right to left, I expect it to work, but it just gets too far.

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/F3XRj/

Answer (score 2):

change 
    position : relative;

to
    position : absolute;

After this is done, the calculation for positioning must take into account the margins and offsets. The easiest way to do this is using jQuery..

```
var handler = function (oEvent)
{
     var Element     = $(this); // get the container

     var oOffset     = Element.offset();
     var Height      = Element.outerHeight();
     var Width       = Element.outerWidth();
     var PosY        = oOffset.top  + Height - oEvent.pageY; // Not necessarily needed for this situation, but useful
     var PosX        = oOffset.left + Width  - oEvent.pageX; // Not necessarily needed for this situation, but useful
     var MarginT     = Element[0].style.marginTop  ? parseInt(Element[0].style.marginTop ) : 0;
     var MarginL     = Element[0].style.marginLeft ? parseInt(Element[0].style.marginLeft) : 0;

     if (Element[0].style)
     {
        Element[0].style.top      = (Element[0].offsetTop  - MarginT) + "px";
        Element[0].style.left     = (Element[0].offsetLeft - MarginL) + "px";
     }
}
```

*The above code is not complete for your situation, but provides the information required to adjust your code, and a strong example of the calculations using css properties to accomplish this goal despite container position or margins

Comment: Absolute does not work..check the JSfiddle and try it

Comment: welcome. :) I have had similar issue myself with positioning a popup while it is being dragged. Please mark as solution if this resolved your issue. :D

Comment: Sorry this is not solution, check it again, my container now is positioned 0 to 0 in the page and we think it works, while it does not work...check the fiddle again with the container getting little bit of margin

Comment: once the criteria has changed. :p I will update with a more accurate answer. I just have to find the code for it

Comment: you misunderstand, the criteria on my end, not yours. I was not expecting a margin or padding since the example did not include this. I am editing with a corrected answer now

Comment: Updated to accommodate for position and margins